# why isn't my form data (using fetch API ) communicated between client and server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, form-data

**disclaimer...**

Looking for some help, I understand this question has been asked (in various ways) before. - However, I've only been coding for some time so relatively new...go easy! ;-)

**My Issue...**

I currently have a react form set up as a functional component, see below:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";


const EmailForm = () => {

    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
      email: "",
      subject: "",
      message: "",
    });
  
    const { email, subject, message } = inputs;
  
    const onChange = e =>
      setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  
    const onSubmitForm = async e => {

      e.preventDefault();
      try {

      const test = { email, subject, message };

      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json", jwt_token: localStorage.token } ,
        body: JSON.stringify(test)
      }

     fetch("http://localhost:5000/dashboard/", options)

      console.log(test, 'SUBMIT')    
    
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    }; 

  
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            placeholder="email" 
            value={email}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            className="form-control my-3"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="subject"
            placeholder="subject"
            value={subject}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            className="form-control my-3"
          />
          <input
          type="textarea"
          name="message"
          placeholder="message" 
          rows="10"
          cols="50"
          value={message} 
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          className="form-control my-3"
          />

          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </Fragment>
    );
  };


export default EmailForm;
```

However, once `onSubmitForm` is actioned I want the form's content (IE - message,email,subject) to be sent to my server in node.js.

I currently have the following set up as a server JS file but when i press the submit button nothing is logged to the console OR in my node.js terminal.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");


//middleware

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//emailForm

app.post("http://localhost:5000/dashboard/"), (req, res) => {
  console.log('i got a message');
  console.log(req.body);
}

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is starting on port 5000`);
});
```

I'm sure it's something really obvious, but any help would be much appreciated. Any ideas?

Thanks team!

Comment: Have you tried to check the requests being sent from the browser developer tools (network tab), ensure that there's no CORS issue, no issues in the host name..etc, in general ensure that the request is being sent to the correct endpoint.

Comment: [Express routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), [Express Tutorial Part 4: Routes and controllers - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes)

Answer (score 0):

You have **three** problems here. Any one of them alone would cause the symptoms you describe.

Look at the [documentation for post](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.post.method).

**First**, the first argument needs to be the **path**, not the **URL**.

**Second**, the callback needs to be the **second argument**, and not a separate expression after a comma operator.

```
app.post('/dashboard/', (req, res) => { ... });
```

---

**Third**, a POST request with a JSON payload requires a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) which you aren't handling. The module you are using has [documentation describing how to set it up for handling preflights](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).

Comment: Firstly, thanks so much! - I suspect it's the preflight request (have amended the others accordingly, thanks!). CORS is accepting all headers/origins etc however when i inspect the 'network' i get a symbol and notified "select the request that triggered this preflight" along with a 204 no content error, I can't figure out how to fix this, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. Parenthesis is at the wrong place.

Instead of :

```
app.post("http://localhost:5000/dashboard/"), something else
```

it should be

```
app.post("http://localhost:5000/dashboard/", (req, res) => { // Remove closing parenthesis
  console.log('i got a message');
  console.log(req.body);
}) // Move it here
```

Comment: Thanks! - Hasn't resolved my issue but great spot :)